# Wrap a group of CSS table cells to a new line

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm experimenting with CSS properties of a two-level set of DOM elements to make it appear like it's a table. The topmost element is just one, it wraps its children, which, in turn, form a flat list of lookalike elements. Like this:

```
<div class="t">
  <div class="c">First row</div>
  <div class="c">2</div>
  <div class="c">3</div>
  <div class="c">4</div>
  <div class="c">5</div>
  <div class="c">Second row</div>
  <div class="c">7</div>
  <div class="c">8</div>
  <div class="c">9</div>
  <div class="c">0</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make this list form two rows, each containing 5 elements. So the CSS I'm using is like:

```
.t {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.c {
  display: table-cell;
}
.c:nth-child(5n + 1):after {
  content: '-';
  display: table-row;
}
```

Which isn't working.

Is there a way to keep two levels of nesting and still have a list that appears as if it was a table?

Answer (score 2):

If you can edit the HTML, just make the structure to like a complete table.

```css
.t {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.r {
  display: table-row;
}
.c {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="t">
  <div class="r">
    <div class="c">First row</div>
    <div class="c">2</div>
    <div class="c">3</div>
    <div class="c">4</div>
    <div class="c">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="r">
    <div class="c">Second row</div>
    <div class="c">7</div>
    <div class="c">8</div>
    <div class="c">9</div>
    <div class="c">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The idea was exactly to not have extra nesting. But it turns out there's no way to work around that, so I'm implementing three-layer structure.

Comment: As far as I know, you will need the additional markup for the proper table layout.

Comment: TBH, I ended up leaving three-layers, and it doesn't hurt as much as I expected. So yep, that seems to be the only viable option. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Yes, as far as I know there isn't a way to do it without breaking the table layout.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what/how you want them to behave, you can use `float`, (haven't tested for cross browser support on this one though) but they will not behave as a normal `table`.

Another option is to use `flexbox` (will still not behave as a normal `table` though)

```css
.t {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.c {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="t">
  <div class="c">First row</div>
  <div class="c">2</div>
  <div class="c">3</div>
  <div class="c">4</div>
  <div class="c">5</div>
  <div class="c">Second row</div>
  <div class="c">7</div>
  <div class="c">8</div>
  <div class="c">9</div>
  <div class="c">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Floats and Flexbox both don't provide equal widths for every nth element in every row. This is why I'm trying to apply `display: table-cell`. To make them automatically equalize their widths.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your expected result, I have used position:relative option and display:table-cell

HTML:

```
<div class="t">
  <div class="c">First row</div>
  <div class="c">2</div>
  <div class="c">3</div>
  <div class="c">4</div>
  <div class="c">5</div>
  <div class="c">Second row</div>
  <div class="c">7</div>
  <div class="c">8</div>
  <div class="c">9</div>
  <div class="c">0</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.t {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.c {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
}

.c:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  top: 60px;
}
```

Codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/mEOjLL

Comment: I have used border just to check the alignment  and width of .class to maintain same width across all divs. Hope this works for you :)